# pyspark/Synapse/python -- Dataframe union is running slow

Tags: dataframe, performance, union

I have a union of six dataframes each having almost 200 columns. The sum of all the records in all 6 dataframes is 90,000 records. The union is taking more than 15 minutes to complete.

I have tried cache() on dataframes and also tried coverting dataframes to temp views for SQL and cache them as well but no improvement in the processing speed.

code:

```
df_final=df_Dedup_final_part1.union(df_Dedup_final_part2).union(df_Dedup_final_part3).union(df_Dedup_final_part4).union(df_Dedup_final_part5).union(df_Dedup_final_part6)
```